# Detect the edge where a lattice changes orientation

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

Rendering the results of a molecular dynamics simulation I've got an image like this,

[image]

where the little spheres represent the atoms of the structure. My goal is to identify the nanoparticles that are distinguishable by the orientation change of the lattice.
For example, I'd like to recognize the edges marked in red, where the lattice changes orientation.

I could apply classification methods directly on the simulation results, rather then render them and analyze the resulting image. But it is not my purpose, because I need a general method suitable for experimental (AFM) images (where the atoms' positions are not given) as well.

[image: AFM image]

I've tried classical edge detection methods (openCV2/python), they identify the edges of every sigle atom, but do not detect the edges of the nanoparticles where the chage of orientation occurs.

Comment: is this the actual quality of your image?

Comment: no I can render it in higher resolution.

Comment: if you can render that image yourself, why do you even have to do any image-processing to get that info? why not process the information you use to render those images?

Comment: because I've those information in xyz format i.e. a list of cartesian coordinates and I need to group the points in a way that is easy to see visually but isn't trivial at all from the coordinates point of view.

Comment: you should provide a lot more context information and present some own attempts or your post will very likely be closed for being too broad. please read [ask]

Comment: It seems that your problem is not really a computer vision but more about classification. If I understood correctly, you want to classify the balls depending on their orientation. An algorithm such as [kNN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) looks more appropriate. But as Piglet said, some details are missing.

Comment: @Piglet  More context it is!